# How to always show the keyboard in a view controller?

Tags: ios, xcode, keyboard, swift2

For looks I would like to keep the ***`Keyboard`*** present in a view controller even if I am not editing any text fields in the view.

In my view controller the user can click a button to go to an image picker to pick an image from the photo library. When I click the imagePicker button this is when the ***`Keyboard`*** goes away.

Is there a way to ***`keep the Keyboard present even when the user clicks the imagePicker?`***

Answer (score 0):

***Yes, you can do it.***

> Since UIKeyboard subclasses UIWindow, the only thing big enough to get
>   in UIKeyboard's way is another UIWindow.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(coverKey) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)coverKey {
    CGRect r = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    UIWindow *myWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(r.size.width - 50 , r.size.height - 50, 50, 50)];
    [myWindow setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [super.view addSubview:myWindow];
    [myWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

**This way the keyboard is never dismissed.**

Comment: This doesn't seem to be doing anything, I updated the question maybe it well help.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have a **TextField**, try implementing this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    checkBool = YES;
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    return checkBool;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    checkBool = NO;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    return NO;
}
```

*If you have a TextView try replacing them with TextView delegate methods.*

Comment: Could you maybe write this in swift if you are able? I tried converting but I am very new to objective c